# Problems in implementing speech recognition in android

Tags: android, speech-recognition, voice-recognition, speech-to-text

I am a beginner in android development and i tried to run the code in this link:

http://www.jameselsey.co.uk/blogs/techblog/android-how-to-implement-voice-recognition-a-nice-easy-tutorial/

But i am experiencing crashing errors. What should I do?

Comment: What error? could you please post log cat

Comment: After i speak a command, the application says "working" and a message displayed "The Application VoiceRecognitionDemo (process com.jameselsey) has stopped unexpectedly." By the way what is logcat? im sorry i am just a beginner in android development.

Comment: Your Problem is Solved or not?

Answer (score 0):

Probably, the permission **RECORD_AUDIO** is missing in the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
     ...
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
</manifest>
```